# Is there any way to get the latest commit date and time for every file in a GitHub repo?

Tags: php, git, api, github

I'm trying to build a tool that will allow me to compare the files in a (private) GitHub repo to the files on a web server.

I have figure out how to query v3 of the GH API to get back a list of all the files in a repo. Something like the following:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo-name/git/trees/sha?recursive=1
```

Where `username`, `repo-name` and `sha` are all variables that I know. This works fine. However, I need to then be able to get the last updated/modified timestamp for each file in the repo so that I can compare that to the last updated/modified timestamp of the associated files on the web server and know where the files in the master branch of the repo are newer than the files on the server.

Is there any way to do this? I've looked thoroughly through the GH API docs, but can't find any way to get the last updated/modified timestamps of files in the repo.

I suppose I could get the timestamp of each GH commit and see what files are in the commit, but for files that haven't been changed/committed in a long time, I'll have to go through too many commits to get the timestamp, which doesn't seem reasonable.

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It'd be quite hard to do using API as you need to scan all commits and list files in every commit. If you can work with a local repo I can point you to 2 scripts. 1st is in [GitWiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ExampleScripts#Setting_the_timestamps_of_the_files_to_the_commit_timestamp_of_the_commit_which_last_touched_them); written in Perl; supposed to work exactly that way—scans commits and get timestamps of files. I had problems running it so I rewrote it in Python; see the script `set-commit-date.py` in my [git-scripts repo](https://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=tree).

Comment: Thanks for those references. Not too familiar with Perl though and not sure how to use the Python repo you linked to. Still, great resources. Thank you.

Comment: [Direct link to the script](https://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=blob_plain;f=set-commit-date.py;hb=HEAD). I must admit I'm also not a Perl programmer, that was one of the reasons I rewrote the script in my preferred language.

Comment: Ah, I see. It parses the git log to determine what to do. Also very clever. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to calculate the hashes of the source files on the web-server and compare the hashes instead of the timestamps.

You can get the git-hash of a source file like this:

```
git hash-object foo.php
```

If you do not have git installed on the web-server, you can use plain bash:

```
printf "blob $(wc -c < foo.php)\0$(cat foo.php)\n" | sha1sum
```

Comment: That's very clever. I like that. Essentially, if the calculated hash of the server file equals the SHA of the GH master repo file, then the file is up to date, right? If the hashes don't match, then the file is out of date and I need to update the file on the server, correct? Thanks.

Comment: jil, I've been playing around with this, and I'm finding the following: I pull down the latest files from a branch, I then push those files to the web server in question, and when I run `git hash-object` on the web server files and compare them to the SHAs on the same files in the GitHub repo, they're not matching. I'm pretty sure I'm getting the files from the correct branch (`dev`) as well. Any thoughts on what might cause this? Thanks.